# Sed with multiple lines does not replace pattern

Tags: sed

I have been massaging with sed (found tutorial here: [Grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) ) ASCII files we get from our hardware suppliers. Files have a structure like so

```
Model-Manufacturer:D12-500
Test_Version:2.6.3
```

But some files we receive are randomly "broken" and miss an entry for "Model-Manufacturer:"

```
Model-Manufacturer:D12-500
Test_Version:2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:H24-700
Test_Version:2.6.3
Test_Version:2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:R15-300
Test_Version:2.6.3
```

I want to fix this problem with Sed and place the missing entry for "Model-Manufacturer:N/A" before the second occurence of "Test_Version:2.6.3" ; this is my code

```
sed -n '
/Test_Version/ {
# found "Test_Version" - read in next line
        N
# look for "Test_Version" on the second line
# and print if there.
        /\n.*Test_Version/ {
# found it - now edit making one line
                s/Test_Version/Model-Manufacturer:N/A/
        }
}' infile > outfile
```

It's not working. I believe I need to remember the position of each "Test_Version" and "Model_Manufacturer" before doing the replacement, correct? Can I do this with sed?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your substitution to:

```
s||\nModel-Manufacturer:N/A&|
```

Using an alternate delimiter means you don't have to escape the slash in "N/A". Using an empty left side reuses the most recent match. The ampersand copies the match into the right side.

Also, you need to remove the `-n`.

Comment: my substitution was off. Yours did the trick. Thank you. On a personal note, sed really kicks a**.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve, you are very close.  I think changing the substitution command to the following makes it work:

```
s/\nTest_Version/\nMode-Manufacturer:N\/A\nTest_Version/
```